# Rails 4 - Controller uses view path of super controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have a SwitchesController that inherits from BaseSwitchesController, for the json.

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SwitchesController < BaseSwitchesController
      respond_to :json
    end
  end
end
```

I have another SwitchesController, also inheriting from BaseSwitchesController, for the html.

```
class SwitchesController < BaseSwitchesController
  layout 'application'
end
```

BaseSwitchesController inherits from ApplicationController.

```
class BaseSwitchesController < ApplicationController
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
    if @switch.update(switch_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @switch, notice: 'Switch was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render json: @switch.as_json.merge(:message => 'set_switch_value') }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @switch.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I want to move the json to the SwitchesController in the API module.
The problem is that the methods in SwitchesController are looking for views in views/base_switches, but that folder doesn't exist. It should be looking for views in views/switches, and choose e.g. index.json.rabl.

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you hard coded render or redirect path in BaseSwitchesController? Show us your BaseSwitchesController

Comment: I've made some changes to the question.

Comment: I would expect Rails to look for views in views/base_switches **and** in views/switches (but not in that order). This is how template inheritance works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't personally mix together API controllers with HTML controllers.

I find two scenarios to be standard.

1. You do not have a traditional API (with it's own restful routes, versioning etc.) and you respond in both html and json. In which case you access the formats with a `.format` extension on the url or by using request headers. This uses the same views for both formats
2. You do have a separated API in which case you would not mix the views together and it allows you to use ActiveRecordSerializers, Rabl or whatever templating method you want to use.

Also your example goes against subclassing. Subclasses should be specializations of your superclass and should contain what differentiates them from other subclasses. Your superclass contains specialized behaviour from both subclasses. Since I'm assuming you don't want to respond to json outside of your API controller.
Hope this helps out

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My biggest problem was that I was copying most of the code (so not very DRY). Do you have any idea how I can solve that? And I wanted to move the specialized behavior to the subclasses, so the code in the superclass was only code that would be used by both the api and the html controller. Just wanted to know your opinion.

Comment: I see your point. Personally I would live with that small duplication but mostly for one reason: independence. That is if you want it. In your example there's not much duplication since you could just render json in one and render html in the other controller, pretty much no duplication. You could also keep them together which is just as well at least for this particular case. For example I would bother making an API when I'm willing to let the two responses differ and to allow for different types of security.